# change schema of a kendo grid angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to rebind a kendo grid in an Angular UI. the schema and data of the datasource will change. I happen to be able to change the data by

> $scope.grid.dataSource.data(data);
>                     $scope.grid.refresh();

but this does not change the schema.

In the non angular world I would have just called grid.destroy and the recreated the grid. but this kills the grid and all bound events.

> $("#grid").removeData('kendoGrid');  $grid.empty();

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have separate `kendo.data.DataSource` objects for each schema, then use the grid's `setDataSource()` method to switch between data sources. [API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setDataSource).

Comment: Thanks Brett. Will try it soon.